# Places auto complete not working properly

Tags: android, adapter, autocompletetextview

I have a `AutompleteTextView` in my app. It is working perfectly fine if I type any character for eg. Lon for London and it shows suggestion perfectly, but if I type some numbers like 12, it doesn't show any suggestion at all, but if I delete one character using backpress then it start showing suggestion. I don't understand why it doesn't show when I type and shows on back press. 
Here is my code

```
 atv_search= (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_search);
            atv_search.setThreshold(1);
            atv_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                   PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();
                    placesTask.execute(charSequence.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
```

AsyncTask and Adapter

```
 private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... place) {
            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
            String key = "key=AIzaSyCgMSD9_CGP2-7lR7O8q-AsPTpUdxV_Z3M";

            String input="";

            try {
                input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // place type to be searched
            String types = "types=geocode";

            // Sensor enabled
            String sensor = "sensor=true";
            String country="&components=country:uk";
            // Building the parameters to the web service
            String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key+"&"+country;

            // Output format
            String output = "json";

            // Building the url to the web service
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;
                  try{
                // Fetching the data from we service
                data = downloadUrl(url);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Creating ParserTask
           ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Starting Parsing the JSON string returned by Web Service
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }
    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

        JSONObject jObject;

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;

            PlaceJsonParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJsonParser();

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            String[] from = new String[] { "description"};
            int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

            // Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);

            // Setting the adapter
            atv_search.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

AutoComplete Textview

```
 public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /** Returns the place description corresponding to the selected item */
    @Override
    protected CharSequence convertSelectionToString(Object selectedItem) {
        /** Each item in the autocompetetextview suggestion list is a hashmap object */
        HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) selectedItem;
        return hm.get("description");
    }
}
```

xml

```
<com.phpexpert.click2eat.utils.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="Enter Postal Code"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:id="@+id/atv_search"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ems="10"
            />
```

Comment: have you enable Google Places API Web Service and show your url?

Comment: yes it is working for text search but causing problem when input is number

Comment: can you post your url which causing problem?

Comment: @KaranMavadhiya it is not a problem with url. I have debug and checked everystep is working properly just dropdown doesn't show with numbers and that is also visible on backpress

Comment: try the last line of my answer.

Comment: its working, I tested in my project, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

use a method after setAdapter();

```
 autocompletetextview.showDropDown();
```

it will works.

Comment: why don't you understand there is problem only with number and that also works on backpress. I have no issue if input is text. Adapter is working properly

Comment: I understood now and its a strange bug, wait.

Comment: You have to use listview for this because AutocompleteTextview not show dropdown when its contain one digit. you can see official google map app also using listview for it.

Comment: its fault of AutocompleteTextview.

Comment: strange to know that it is a bug but same thing is working in another app with bit different code

Comment: no we can do this by autocompletetextview, and  I fix this bug, and this method is working well on my project.

Answer (score 0):

Because by default sequence that start with number is not text, Filter don't show dropdown. when you press backspace Filter start checking (backspace is not number!)

so, You can add `atv_search.showDropDown()` to `onTextChanged` to show all time user type his/her text.

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
    int count) {
        //YOUR CODE
        if (atv_search.enoughToFilter()) {
            atv_search.showDropDown();
        }
    }
```